# rails render file from rest service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I'm new on ruby on rails and 'm trying to get a file generated from a rest service in java through rest client on rails.

First my rest service ( java ) code:

```
    @GET
    @Produces({"application/pdf"})
    @Path("/getPDF")
    public StreamingOutput getPDF() throws Exception {
        return new StreamingOutput() {
            public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                try {
                    // step 1
                    Document document = new Document();
                    // step 2
                    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);
                    // step 3
                    document.open();
                    // step 4
                    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
                    document.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));
                    // step 5
                    document.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new WebApplicationException(e);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

testing my code I actually get the pdf file

[image]

In rails I'm trying to render the file like this:

```
def formato    
pdf = RestClient.get "http://localhost:8084/ause/servicios/usuario/getPDF"

send_file pdf, type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline'
end
```

But I'm getting this on the browser:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `UsarioEdit`? There's not really enough information here - it appears the error is how `formato` method is producing PDF data.

Comment: `send_file` is expecting a file not a stream have you tried `send_data` instead since it appears your Java application is streaming not saving to a file.

Comment: send_data actually works! - @engineersmnky

Comment: No problem glad I could help